# filter a N-D numpy array and keep only specific elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm dealing with a large N-D numpy array. I would like to keep only those elements present in a different numpy array, and set the remaining values to 0.

for example, if we consider this numpy array

```
array([[[36,  1, 72],
        [76, 50, 23],
        [28, 68, 17],
        [84, 75, 69]],

       [[ 5, 15, 93],
        [92, 92, 88],
        [11, 54, 21],
        [87, 76, 81]]])
```

and I want to set `0` in all places except where the values are `50`, `11`, `72`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, i took the simple approach of iterating over the list and setting replacing the value to zero, and I was sure that it was not the best approach

Comment: There's no list here. Terminology is important, as is providing an example of your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a mask by combining `reduce` with `np.logical_or` and iterated over the values that should remain:

```
import functools
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[36,  1, 72],
        [76, 50, 23],
        [28, 68, 17],
        [84, 75, 69]],
       [[ 5, 15, 93],
        [92, 92, 88],
        [11, 54, 21],
        [87, 76, 81]]])

# Set the values that should not
# be set to zero
vals = [11, 50, 72]

# Create a mask by looping over the above values
mask = functools.reduce(np.logical_or, (arr==val for val in vals))

masked = np.where(mask, arr, 0.)

print(masked)
> array([[[ 0.,  0., 72.],
        [ 0., 50.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [11.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are onto using only `numpy`, this can also be done using simple use of broadcasting by casting the `vals` array to just one rank higher than `a`. This is accomplished without using iterations or other functionalities.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[36,  1, 72],
         [76, 50, 23],
         [28, 68, 17],
         [84, 75, 69]],
 
        [[ 5, 15, 93],
         [92, 92, 88],
         [11, 54, 21],
         [87, 76, 81]]])

vals = np.array([50, 11, 72])
inds = a == vals[:, None, None, None]
a[~np.any(inds, axis = 0)] = 0
a
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 0,  0, 72],
        [ 0, 50,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [11,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0]]])
```