# faster deleting/masking few entries from a large index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an index manipulation problem that I can solve, but it's slow. I'm looking for a way to speed this up.

I have a large `(m, 2)` float array (think 2D point coordinates) and a large `idx` array into `points`. (A typical operation is to pick indices out, `points[idx]`.) From `idx`, I sometimes need to delete a few entries. I can do that with `mask`, but the operation is slow, presumably because the entire array is rewritten in memory. Alternative: [numpy's masked arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html). Masking is fast, of course, but unfortunately they don't work as indices: the masking is simply ignored.

MWE:

```py
import numpy

# setup
points = numpy.random.rand(10, 2)
n = 5  # can be very large irl
idx = numpy.random.randint(0, 10, n)

# typical operation with idx:
# points[idx]

# a few entries are deleted
mask = numpy.ones(n, dtype=bool)
mask[2] = False  # only a few are masked
idx = idx[mask]  # takes a while

# alternative: use ma?
idx = numpy.random.randint(0, 10, n)
idx = numpy.ma.array(idx)
idx[2] = numpy.ma.masked
# Doesn't work, masking is ignored:
points[idx]
```

Any hints on how to speed this up?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034699/filter-a-n-d-numpy-array-and-keep-only-specific-elements#65034699 check if this will help you, it was answered few minutes ago

Comment: `idx = idx.compressed()` removes the masked terms from the `ma` array.  In general `MaskedArrays` have to be used with their own functions/methods.  Other `numpy` code just works with the `data` attribute.  They won't improve speed in your case.

Comment: `points[idx]` is an new array regardless of how you generated `idx` (as array of indices or boolean array).  The operation time roughly depends on the total number of elements in the result.  There's no way around the copying.  This is called `advanced indexing` (as opposed to `basic` indexing which creates a `view`).